# spring boot war deployment url with api gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, url, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am using spring boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE.
I have developed on service using spring boot and used Eureka service register, Zuul API Gateway.
My applications pom file application name is "TestApplication"

```
<build>
    <finalName>TestApplication</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And tomcat deployed war name is "testservice.war".

So when I access the URL of application using API Gateway it is formed like below

```
http://localhost:8080/ApiGateway/testapplication/testservice/swagger-ui.html
```

format: zuul api gateway context/ applicationname/contextname

I want to avoid context name (testservice) in the url and access with eureka registered name only like below:

```
http://localhost:8080/ApiGateway/testservice/swagger-ui.html
```

Comment: Do you use embedded tomcat??

Comment: No I dont use embedded tomcat, I have deployed war in tomcat instance

Answer (score 0):

You can add a route to Zuul `.properties` file, something like :

```
zuul.routes.testapplication.path=/testapplication
zuul.routes.testapplication.service-id=testapplication
```

Then you can call your service like this : `http://APIGATEWAY:8080/testapplication/swagger-ui.html/`